# New intent wont start inside onLongPress?

Tags: android, android-intent, ondraw

I have created a TapGestureDetector class for a surface view.there i catch the Long touch event and i want to start a new activity.But its not working. The Intent is not starting. There's an Null Pointer exception. I have defined the action in the manifest as well as the intent. But there's an error which i cant identify.

```
 public class TapGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

int touchX;
int touchY;
public static String block_name;
Context ctx = custom.ctx;
ArrayList<Rect> rectangles = storeMap.GetArrayList();


@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {

//Detect touched X.Y
    touchX = (int) event.getX();
    touchY = (int) event.getY();
//Go through a set of rectangles and identify the touched rectangle
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.size(); i++) {

        if (rectangles.get(i).contains(touchX, touchY)) {

            rectangles.get(i).describeContents();
            String Selected_rect = String.valueOf(rectangles.get(i));
            Store_Identified_Block.Store(Selected_rect);
            getSelectedCoordinates();


            //Start a new intent
            Intent myIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.zoomlevel");
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            //This is not working
            try {
                ctx.startActivity(myIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.d("onLongPress(MotionEvent event)", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            break;
        }
    }

super.onLongPress(event);
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace from logcat and indicate relevant line numbers in the code.

Comment: i'd assume custom.ctx is obviously null

Comment: Yes u are correct.. ctx was my context which i got from anotehr class.. but now i fixed it and its working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it :)

```
try {

                Intent mm=new Intent(finalmainvclass.maincontaxt,zoomlevel.class);
                mm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                finalmainvclass.maincontaxt.startActivity(mm);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.d("MYLOG", "Error is "+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```